# Django - как убрать повторяющиеся объекты во вьюхе?

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Локация", default=u'')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Страна", default=u'')

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u"Страна")

class Photo(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, verbose_name=u'Фото')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ['name', 'country']


photos = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10)

def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(LocationForm, self).save(commit)
    for each in self.cleaned_data['photos']:
        Photo.objects.create(photo=each, location=instance)

    return instance
```

views.py

```
class AddLocationPageView(CreateView):
    model = Location
    form_class = LocationForm
    template_name = 'add_location.html'

class BrowseLocationsPageView(ListView):
    model = Country
    context_object_name = 'countries'
    template_name = "browse_locations.html"
```

add_location.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

browse_locations.html

```
{% for country in countries %}
            {{ country }}
{% endfor %}
```

Мне нужно получить в browse_locations.html список стран без повторения. Например, я добавляю объект локации со страной США, затем я добавляю другой объект тоже страна США. Но во вьюхе мне надо видеть не все объекты Country (которые дублируются), а только по одному.

Спасибо!!!

Comment: По вашему коду не понятно как вообще модель Country связана с Location, может быть там ForeignKey? Откуда в Country берутся записи?

Comment: Переопределите queryset в LocationForm с distinct('country')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В browse_locations.html у вас и так все правильно, не должно быть дубликатов. Вам надо в модели Location, поле country сделать ForeignKey на модель Country.

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Локация", default=u'')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name=u"Страна")

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u"Страна")
```

Также, Вам потребуется отдельная форма для добавления стран, ну либо через админку добавить или через sql проинсертить - их не так много.

Comment: сделал... при создании локации поле формы Страна выдает ошибку - Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices. ... разумеется это чойса нет еще ведь я только создаю локацию и первый раз создаю страну

Comment: @Denis, Я же Вам писал выше, что потребуется создать отдельную форму для заполнения стран. Либо через sql заполните.

Comment: @Denis, sql вставки страны: INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('Россия');