# Django - ругается поле формы при создании объекта

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Локация", default=u'')
    country = models.ForeignKey("Country")

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u"Страна")

class Photo(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, verbose_name=u'Фото')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ['name', 'country']


photos = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10)

def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(LocationForm, self).save(commit)
    for each in self.cleaned_data['photos']:
        Photo.objects.create(photo=each, location=instance)

    return instance
```

views.py

```
class AddLocationPageView(CreateView):
    model = Location
    form_class = LocationForm
    template_name = 'add_location.html'

class BrowseLocationsPageView(ListView):
    model = Country
    context_object_name = 'countries'
    template_name = "browse_locations.html"
```

add_location.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

browse_locations.html

```
{% for country in countries %}
            {{ country }}
{% endfor %}
```

При создании объекта Location поле формы Страна ругается:
"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

Разумеется у меня нет никаких чойсов, так как замысел такой, что при отсутствии страны в БД она должна создаваться в момент создания Локации, а при наличии (допустим кто-то уже создал какую-то локацию с такой страной) - привязываться к Локации.

Спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Django - как убрать повторяющиеся объекты во вьюхе?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529573/django-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%85%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример формы, которая будет делать так, как вы хотите:

```py
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Country')
    photos = forms.MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['name',]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        country_name = self.cleaned_data['country']
        country, created = Country.objects.get_or_create(name=country_name)
        self.instance.country = country
        instance = super(LocationForm, self).save(commit)

        for each in self.cleaned_data['photos']:
            Photo.objects.create(photo=each, location=instance)

        return instance
```